# bash prompt doesn't re-draw properly on resizing window

Tags: bash, ubuntu, prompt, gnome-terminal

Basically I have a bottom bar that always shows me the current directory on the left and on the right side the git branch. I tried to use powerline, but it only works by having a bar above the prompt, which is not what i wanted.

I now face some issues when resizing the window that i have weird artifacts of the bottom bar. I am on using the standard terminal that comes with a standard ubuntu 20.04 installation.

This is my prompt (I know, it's quite complicated and maybe a bit ugly...)

```
plen() {
   local ps len
   ps="$(perl -pe 's|\\\[.*?\\\]||g' <<<" \u  \w")"
   len="$(wc -m <<<"${ps@P}")"
   printf '%s\n' "$((len))"
}

getCPos () { 
    local v=() t=$(stty -g)
    stty -echo
    tput u7
    IFS='[;' read -rd R -a v
    stty $t
    CPos=(${v[@]:1})
}

update-ps() {
  local EXIT="$?"
  local CSI=$'\e'"["
  local LEFT_STATEMENT="${CSI}48;5;32m \u ${CSI}40m \w${CSI}0;0m"
  local CURRENT_COLS=$(tput cols)
  local RIGHT_STATEMENT=$(__git_ps1 "  %s")
  local LEFT_LENGTH=$(plen "$LEFT_STATEMENT")
  local TOTAL_LENGTH=$(echo "${LEFT_LENGTH} + ${#RIGHT_STATEMENT}" | bc)
  local HPA_RIGHT=$(echo "$CURRENT_COLS - ${#RIGHT_STATEMENT}" | bc)

  if [[ $TOTAL_LENGTH -gt $CURRENT_COLS ]] || [[ ${#RIGHT_STATEMENT} -lt 1 ]]
  then
    RIGHT_STATEMENT=""
  else
    RIGHT_STATEMENT="$(tput hpa ${HPA_RIGHT})${RIGHT_STATEMENT}"
  fi

  local BOTTOM_BAR="\[${CSI}s${CSI}1;$((LINES-1))r${CSI}$LINES;1f${LEFT_STATEMENT}${CSI}40m${CSI}K${RIGHT_STATEMENT}${CSI}K${CSI}u\]"

  if [ $EXIT == 0 ]; then
    local USER_INPUT="\[\033[48;5;28m\] $ \[\033[0;0m\] "
  else
    local USER_INPUT="\[\033[48;5;1m\] $ \[\033[0;0m\] "
  fi

  # Somehow, e.g. when using vim and prompt was at LINE-1, then it get's stuck in the last line. A small workaround for this issue.
  getCPos
  if [[ $CPos -gt $((LINES - 1)) ]]
  then
    export PS1="\n${BOTTOM_BAR}$(tput cup $((LINES-2)))${USER_INPUT}"
  else
    export PS1="${BOTTOM_BAR}${USER_INPUT}"
  fi

}

PROMPT_COMMAND="update-ps;$PROMPT_COMMAND"
```

Comment: This is how a terminal shell is designed. In a GUI/Web-based world, people come to expect resizing windows to trigger a "reflow" event to redraw the screen. Shells have no such event. Terminal programs which interact with the shell _may_ have some _limited_ support for reflows, but only in certain scenarios. Precise placement of any text, such as a "statusbar" on a text-based "screen" breaks this, because the screen positions are calculated at the time of _output_, _not_ the time of _viewing_.

Answer (score 1):

The issue you are facing is that the "status bar" on the bottom line of your terminal is written at the same time as (since it is effectively a part of) your shell prompt.  This process in part determines the size of your terminal *at the time the prompt is written to the screen*.  As such, if you resize the terminal afterward, there is no way for the items already written to the terminal to know what the size of the terminal will be (or indeed that it will be resized at all).  Unfortunately, without Sisyphean degrees of toil, it will be difficult if not impossible to make a prompt-generated rendering such as that reactive to terminal geometry changes.